# Why is Blender slowing down?

Tags: interface

This is something I have never witnessed with any software before.

When I open Blender it works properly; I click on an object, vertex, etc., and it lights up immediately.

But after about half an hour of work it can take up to a full second before it lights up, and commands start to yield awkward results.
After an hour it can take up to 5 seconds before a clicked item lights up, and commands are yielding weirder results.

My processor is not being taxed in any way, nor is my memory.

I close the software and reopen it and everything works fine again. But after half an hour it slows down again.

Is this programmed in the free version to annoy people who can't pay for the pro version? Because I can't find any logical reason why the software slows down through time during usage.

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: What Pro version?

Comment: There's no Pro Version.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that Blender might get bogged down by the number of steps you have performed which it stores in RAM, in order for you to **Undo** your actions.
The default value for this is 32 steps, and you can change this in your Preferences:

[image]

As you can see, you can also set a memory limit to these steps.

**There is no paid or pro version of Blender**. There is no bad programming to pester people who don't pay for this software, there is no planned obsolescence - it's free and open source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i doubt that would be the case. I set it at 64 steps and left undo memory at unlimited (0)for safety and i have more than enough memory to handle that. I worked with other 3d animation software (3Dmax, maya, even rhino) and never had that problem. (To those you were vexed by me asking about pro version, don't be so shocked most software have free version filled with flaws and bugs).

Comment: You doubt that would be the case, but have you tried it? It might be related to the actual problem. Try setting it at 8 Undo Steps or something, and just manually save often, just to see if that helps.

Comment: I moved it to 64 in the hopes that it would stop doing that, but it didn't change a thing.plus due to my inexperience i make many mistakes that sometimes requires me to retrace my steps back a lot. And saving under a different name every 9th steps would be tedious. Plus i can't see any hardware or software reasons for such a thing to happen. Not even half of my ram is occupied, only one of the core is being used but barely. And i can't see how the amounts of undo steps would cause the software to become sluggish with time. Other software don't so why would blender. Must be something else.